# cmp or diff and then replace disk image

Tags: hard-disk, diff, external-hdd

Supposing that I have two disk images (2TB) (one is copy of the other) and then I do changes in one. Surely I could  use `diff` or `cmp` for see changes. Now I can apply the changes in the another.

#### Example:

- DomoImage.raw is a original file (2TB):

  The copy is DomoImage1.raw(2TB + 15g of new files)...

  Now I want write changes of DomoImage1.raw in > DomoImage.raw but I want not overwrite all 2TB, only add new changes (15g of files)

**EDIT:** is possible do it with **`rsync`** ??

*NOTE: I can't mount images like hdd for see files, only can see entire disk or put it in `/dev/loop0` with losetup*

Question: How could I Insert the new changes in the original image?

Answer (score 2):

A disk image contains much more than just the data occupied by the files, and neither `cmp` nor `diff` would (easily) be able to produce a "patch" between the disk images.

You'd be better of just copying the new image, or possibly using something like `rsync` to sync the images (but I've never used `rsync` for that amount of data). I don't know which of these two approaches would be quickest (because this is your main concern, right?).

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem is the time take by process of writing all hdd, because I want only add new changes like diff... :D

Comment: @Milor123 Anything like `diff` that just looks the raw images (instead of mounting them as filesystems) will have to read both entire files in order to *find* the changes. This means it can't be much faster than just copying the entire file.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Ahhhh now know, thank you very much dude